# When should one apply for a PhD in the UK?

Tags: phd, united-kingdom

In September 2021 I will be starting a Master's degree course in Economics, and I want to pursue a PhD after its completion. The Master's course finishes by September 2022. However this raises a problem. If I want to start the PhD course in September/October 2022, I would have to start applying/searching for funding for the PhD right as I begin my Master's degree, this September. At the same time, if I decide to apply for a PhD only after finishing my Master's degree, I would probably start the PhD in September/October 2023.

On the one hand I would prefer to start working on a PhD programme as early as possible and it would feel like I have wasted on an entire year just for applications if I were to start in 2023. On the other hand, if I start applying this September (for late 2022 entry), I feel like my chances of securing funding or making a good proposal could be lower since by that time I would only be starting on my Masters course, and so would not even have a thesis continue my work on.

At this point, I am open to all advice or experience that people have with this issue. I hope everyone is well and thank you very much in advance for your time, advice and kind consideration. Sorry, if my explanations are a little unclear due to the dating.

Comment: _I would have to start applying/searching for funding for the PhD right as I begin my Master's degree, this September_: This is surely common amongst all applicants following a similar path. _At the same time, if I decide to apply for a PhD only after finishing my Master's degree, I would probably start the PhD in September/October 2023_: Why not start between September/October 2022 and September/October 2023?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everyone doing a Master's is in the same boat. PhD applications aren't usually due until late January or early February, so that's a good four or five months into your Master's course. This gives you plenty of time to work on the applications and get to know your lecturers to secure a reference letter or two.

Plus, you may end up working on something completely different for your PhD than you did for your Master's so it doesn't really matter how far along in your Master's work you are at the time of applying for PhDs. Furthermore, admissions committees are fully aware of this situation.

Good luck with the applications.